# Configuring multiple NICs programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I am an engineering student doing a project on autonomous vision based navigation of multiple Ar Drones (simple quad-rotor UAV).

I have interfaced two WiFi cards in my PC. Both the Ar Drones make their own WiFi server. I connect each of the two NICs to both of them (AR Drones) simultaneously. Both the drones are transmitting a video stream using a UDP port.

My question is this :

1. Can I receive both the video streams simultaneously?
2. If yes, then how to configure my C# application to receive both these video streams and display them?

I can already receive video stream from one Drone. How to re-configure that code to receive both the video streams?

Comment: Can you provide what code you have already?  It may help in trying to understand where the limitation is.

Comment: we need more details. what libraries are you using?

Comment: i am using a C# SDK... The link is  https://github.com/shtejv/ARDrone-Control-.NET ...

Comment: in this SDK the project under the name of "ARDroneControlLibrary" contains a file "DroneConfig.cs" ... Plz view that

Answer (score 0):

You need two sockets, and you want to [`bind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind.aspx) each one to the address of the corresponding network interface.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 WiFi cards for that.

Basically, your client application needs to create 2 sockets. Each one can listen to a different port (ex: 5000 and 5001). Then you must communicate this info to your drone. Probably by connecting your client application to your drone in TCP and sending the configuration for each drone. The first drone will receive port 5000 and the second one will receive port 5001.

Then, the drone must transmit the data in UDP to the IP address of your client machine and to the specified port in the configuration.

**EDIT:**
I have checked the library and I see a UdpWorker class which is used to send UDP data. When calling the constructor of this class, you must provide the remote IP address (address of the client app) and the port number.

Suppose your client has the IP 192.168.1.1, then the Drone#1 will initialize an UdpWorker object with remoteIpAddress=192.168.1.1 and port=5000. For the Drone#2, an UdpWorker object will be initialized with remoteIpAddress=192.168.1.1 and port=5001.

Your client app will receive both streams from different sockets since both sockets are bond to different ports so it is easy differentiate which one is which. In your C# application, you can instantiate 2 objects of type System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient. The first one is initialized with port number 5000 and the second with port number 5001.

Comment: well the problem is that once one drone is connected via WiFi the link cannot be used to connect another drone. The WiFi server created by the drone can only be connected to one client

Comment: Each drone communicates only with the C# client. There is only one communication per drone. It's just that the C# client application listens to 2 different ports on the same address. Drone#1 sends data to client on port X and Drone#2 send data to client on port Y.

Comment: I have updated my answer with info related to the library you use for the drones.

Comment: thnx ... i got your point ... i just am not sure about one thing. i have to use two NICs rite??  ..  incase you say no than  how can windows connect to two servers using one NIC

Comment: You only need 1 NIC. When you connect your web browser to 2 different web servers, you use the same NIC. It's the same thing. This is basic networking. Please refer to this book: http://bafff.ru/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/TCPIP_Fund.pdf. It explains how everything works under the hood.